# How do I know which universities in Germany have higher external research funding?

Tags: university, germany

How can I know which universities receive greater investment from industry for research purposes?

My major is *Computer Science* or *Informatik*, and  specifically need this data for Germany.

I am going to apply for a PhD position, and my main motivation is to get connected with huge companies, such as Amazon or Google, which have some running research projects in universities. So I just thought, maybe the external research investment can show which university has more connection to industry?

For example [*Electrical Engineering and Computer Science of TUB*](https://www.eecs.tu-berlin.de/menue/research/parameter/en/) claims that they have one of the richest department in the whole Germany, so I am wondering if I can find stat about such claim.

Comment: You might want to look into reports from DFG, but that's not everything, as @Snijderfrey mentioned.

Comment: Having experience specifically in CS and Germany, I think that flow of money from industry to universities is the exception rather than the rule. Most funding is taxpayer money (e.g., DFG, BMBF and EU projects).

Comment: The study guide of the newspaper "Die Zeit" has data on the mean amount of third party funding per professor, grouped by courses of study.

Comment: @DCTLib Do you have a link about the `Die Zeit` report ?

Comment: "my main motivation is to get connected with huge companies, such as Amazon or Google" If your main motivation is establishing a connection with US internet giants, why do you intend to do your PhD in Germany?

Comment: Rather than looking at universities at a whole, I would look at at publications in your area of interest and see which of them were published jointly by a company with a university lab. Joint research projects are often between company and professor, not company and university.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, Jimmy. The guide is available at https://ranking.zeit.de/che/de/, but it will not distinguish between public and private third-party funding. Note that the page that you linked to @TU Berlin does explicitly *not* say that they are one of the richest departments. They say that they are one of the "strongest research departments", and *then* they talk about how much money they are getting from third-part sources. The first sentence does not necessary refer to money, and if you look at the German version of the page, this actually becomes clear.

Comment: There are several reasons to severely doubt whether the total amount of industry funding of a CS department is a good predicator of whether you'll be able to "get connected with huge companies" when you do your PhD there.

Comment: And it is also doubtful whether doing a PhD is the right choice when your primary goal ist to get connections to industry (maybe except for PhD projects which are specifally part of a cooperation between a company and and a "Lehrstuhl").

Answer (score 5):

This data is quite conveniently summarized in the [DFG Förderatlas](https://www.dfg.de/sites/foerderatlas2021/). There is a graph on page 45 of the pdf showing the percentages of different funding sources at different universities and on page 47 you can find absolute volumes of funding for different fields at different universities. I am note sure if you can find the funding of CS at TU Berlin split up for different sources, though.

[image]